# How can i sort values based on a specific condition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-01-2020'],
                  'Shift':['A','A','A','A','A'],
                  'heat_number':['HA1','HA10','HA8','HA18A','HA5']})
```

Looking like this

```
    Date        Shift   heat_number
0   01-01-2020    A        HA1
1   01-01-2020    A        HA10
2   01-01-2020    A        HA8
3   01-01-2020    A        HA18A
4   01-01-2020    A        HA5
5   01-01-2020    A        HA18
```

if i do `df.sort_values(['Date','Shift',heat_number])`
I get the below output:

```
    Date         Shift  heat_number
0   01-01-2020    A        HA1
1   01-01-2020    A        HA10
5   01-01-2020    A        HA18
3   01-01-2020    A        HA18A
4   01-01-2020    A        HA5
2   01-01-2020    A        HA8
```

But my desired output is:

```
    Date         Shift  heat_number
0   01-01-2020    A        HA1
4   01-01-2020    A        HA5
2   01-01-2020    A        HA8
1   01-01-2020    A        HA10
5   01-01-2020    A        HA18
3   01-01-2020    A        HA18A
```

Filter in the heat number column is not as per expectation. How can i fix this?

Comment: There's a pull request `[https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3942#issuecomment-508588258]` regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, Assign new psuedo columns to the dataFrame [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) which is extract of `heat_number`, apply [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) on the psuedo column. Finally [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) psuedo columns

```
(
    df.assign(sort_by=df.heat_number.str.extract("(\d+)").astype(int))
        .sort_values(by="sort_by")
        .drop(columns="sort_by")
)
```

---

```
         Date Shift heat_number
0  01-01-2020     A         HA1
4  01-01-2020     A         HA5
2  01-01-2020     A         HA8
1  01-01-2020     A        HA10
3  01-01-2020     A       HA18A
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
df['len_heat']  = df.heat_number.str.len()

df = df.sort_values(['Date','Shift',"len_heat"])

del df['len_heat']
```

Basically, it adds a column which has the length of string, sorts and drops this column.